# Express: Add prefix to serving url

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, prefix

I'm trying to do the following.
I have a server that listens to a certain port (let's say `4242`).
The url that redirects to that port is `http://myUrl/prefix`.
So basically I need to serve my express app with that prefix.
The problem is that express uses this url for the directories dist, public, etc..:
`http://myUrl/dist`. Whereas I want it to be `http://myUrl/prefix/dist`.

Is it possible to achieve that?

I tried to add the prefix in the app.use, like for example:
`app.use('/prefix/dist', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')));`

instead of:
`app.use('/dist', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')));`

I don't know if it changes anything, but my front framework is Vue.js

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your entire app on that prefix with the statement

```js
express().use("/prefix", app).listen(4242);
```

The `prefix` only appears in this statement, nowhere in the Javascript code for the app. But if the app needs to know it, it can use [`app.mountpath`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.mountpath).